# How to hide RadToolBarButton from C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik

In my application i am using two RadToolBarButtons. Some times i want to hide one RadToolBarButton from C#.

Here i want to hide first one i.e Save Filter. How to get this RadToolBarButton id in C#.

```
 <telerik:RadToolBar ID="CandidatesToolBar" runat="server" EnableRoundedCorners="True"
                 Width="100%" Height="24px" EnableShadows="True">
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadToolBarButton Text="Save Filter" ToolTip="Click here to Save the filter search" CommandName="SavePopUp"></telerik:RadToolBarButton>
                    <telerik:RadToolBarButton Text="Saved Filter" ToolTip="Click here to View Saved search filter" CommandName="SavedPopUp"></telerik:RadToolBarButton>
                    <telerik:RadToolBarButton Text="Clear Filter" ToolTip="Click here to clear the filter search" CommandName="ClearFilter"/>
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadToolBar>
```

C#:

```
  private void HideSavefilter()
        {
            int CandidatesTableCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["VendorCandidateListTableCount"].ToString());
            int CandidatesRowsCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["VendorCandidateListRowsCount"].ToString());
            try
            {

                if (CandidatesTableCount > 0 && CandidatesRowsCount > 0)
                {
                    foreach (RadToolBarItem btn in CandidatesToolBar.Items)
                    {
                        if (btn.GetType().FullName == "Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolBarButton" && btn.Text == "Save Filter")
                        {
                            btn.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }

                }
                else if (CandidatesTableCount == 0)
                {
                    foreach (RadToolBarItem btn in CandidatesToolBar.Items)
                    {
                        if (btn.GetType().FullName == "Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolBarButton" && btn.Text == "Save Filter")
                        {
                            btn.Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch { }
        }
```

Please tell me how to do this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your Bar buttons are wrapped inside a RadToolBar.

```
<telerik:RadToolBar ID="MyRadToolBar" runat="server">
<Items>
<telerik:RadToolBarButton Text="Save Filter" ToolTip="Click here to Save the filter search" CommandName="SavePopUp"></telerik:RadToolBarButton>
 <telerik:RadToolBarButton Text="Saved Filter" ToolTip="Click here to View Saved search filter" CommandName="SavedPopUp"></telerik:RadToolBarButton>       
</Items>
</telerik:RadToolBar>
```

then find the item by text and hide

```
Dim barItem As RadToolBarItem = Me.MyRadToolBar.FindItemByText("Save Filter")
Dim radButton = CType(barItem, RadToolBarButton)
radButton.Visible = False
```

c#

```
RadToolBarItem barItem = this.MyRadToolBar.FindItemByText("Save Filter");
RadToolBarButton radButton =(RadToolBarButton)barItem;
radButton.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Thank you, But i want it in C#.NET. Not in VB.NET.

Comment: I converted your code into C#.   RadToolBarItem barItem = this.CandidatesToolBar.FindItemByText("Save Filter");
                    RadToolBarItem radButton = (RadToolBarButton)barItem;
                    radButton.Visible = false;  but it is not working.

Comment: I was wondering why you say this isn't working. I copied the exact code you updated and tested with some hardcoded values to CandidatesTableCount and the button gets hide nicely. When you say this isn't working what do you mean ? You get any error? what happens when u debug? I'm curious. May be you dont get values to your session variables as u expect.

Comment: Its working fine in new page. But in my application it is not working.May be its my application problem. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**ASPX.CS**

```
foreach (RadToolBarButton btn in RadToolBar1.Items)
{
    if (btn.Text == "Save Filter")
    {
        btn.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

**ASPX**

```
 <telerik:RadToolBar ID="RadToolBar1" runat="server">
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadToolBarButton Text="Save Filter" ToolTip="Click here to Save the filter search" CommandName="SavePopUp"></telerik:RadToolBarButton>
                    <telerik:RadToolBarButton Text="Saved Filter" ToolTip="Click here to View Saved search filter" CommandName="SavedPopUp"></telerik:RadToolBarButton>
                </Items>
  </telerik:RadToolBar>
```

UPDATE 1:

```
foreach (RadToolBarItem btn in RadToolBar1.Items)
{
    if (btn.GetType().FullName == "Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolBarButton" && btn.Text == "Save Filter")
    {
        btn.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error, Unable to cast object of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolBarDropDown' to type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolBarButton'.

Comment: Thank you. I updated your code but it is not working.

Comment: I updated my code above. Please check. Thank you Jayesh Goyani.

Comment: I have tried with your code, it works for me. Can you please try your code in new page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47671/discussion-between-1612-and-jayesh-goyani)